# how to export a constant list as part of a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I have the following simple class.

I would like to include a `static list` as part of it's export definition.

```
// DataService.js

    import Api from '@/services/Api'

    export default {
      // const states = ['ABIA', 'ADAMAWA', 'AKWA IBOM', 'ANAMBRA', 'BAUCHI', 'BAYELSA', 'BENUE', 'BORNO', 'CROSS RIVER', 'DELTA', 'EBONYI', 'EDO', 'EKITI', 'ENUGU', 'FCT(ABUJA)', 'GOMBE', 'IMO', 'JIGAWA', 'KADUNA', 'KANO', 'KATSINA', 'KEBBI', 'KOGI', 'KWARA', 'LAGOS', 'NASARAWA', 'NIGER', 'OGUN', 'ONDO', 'OSUN', 'OYO', 'PLATEAU', 'RIVERS', 'SOKOTO', 'TARABA', 'YOBE', 'ZAMFARA'],

      list (entity, p) { return Api().get(entity, {params: p}) },
      get (entity, id) { return Api().get(entity + '/' + id) },
      create (entity, o) { return Api().post(entity, o) },
      update (entity, idField, o) { return Api().put(entity + '/' + o[idField], o) },
      delete (entity, id) { return Api().delete(entity + '/' + id) }

    }
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the states array out of the class an export it as a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports):

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export const states = ['ABIA', 'ADAMAWA', 'AKWA IBOM', 'ANAMBRA', 'BAUCHI', 'BAYELSA', 'BENUE', 'BORNO', 'CROSS RIVER', 'DELTA', 'EBONYI', 'EDO', 'EKITI', 'ENUGU', 'FCT(ABUJA)', 'GOMBE', 'IMO', 'JIGAWA', 'KADUNA', 'KANO', 'KATSINA', 'KEBBI', 'KOGI', 'KWARA', 'LAGOS', 'NASARAWA', 'NIGER', 'OGUN', 'ONDO', 'OSUN', 'OYO', 'PLATEAU', 'RIVERS', 'SOKOTO', 'TARABA', 'YOBE', 'ZAMFARA'];

export default {
  list (entity, p) { return Api().get(entity, {params: p}) },
  get (entity, id) { return Api().get(entity + '/' + id) },
  create (entity, o) { return Api().post(entity, o) },
  update (entity, idField, o) { return Api().put(entity + '/' + o[idField], o) },
  delete (entity, id) { return Api().delete(entity + '/' + id) }
}
```

To [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module) the states:

```
import { states } from './modulePath
```

To import the states and the class:

```
import moduleName, { states } from './modulePath
```

Comment: Please how will it then be accessed? DataService.states ?

Comment: import moduleName, { states } from './modulePath`

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. I've added links to export and import.